# Tails ISO Signature not Showing in Directory

Tags: tails

Downloaded the cryptographic signature corresponding to the ISO image I want to verify, and saved it in the same folder as the ISO image:

Started the cryptographic verification:

```
`MacBook-Pro:ISO Stello$ gpg --keyid-format long --verify tails-i386-1.0.1.iso.sig tails-i386-1.0.1.iso
gpg: can't open signed data `tails-i386-1.0.1.iso'
gpg: can't hash datafile: No such file or directory
MacBook-Pro:ISO Stello$ 
`
```

What it should look like:

```
cd [the ISO image directory]
gpg --keyid-format long --verify tails-i386-1.0.1.iso.sig tails-i386-1.0.1.iso

gpg: Signature made Sat 30 Apr 2011 10:53:23 AM CEST
gpg:                using RSA key 1202821CBE2CD9C1
gpg: Good signature from "Tails developers (signing key) <tails@boum.org>"
```

Now, I imported the Tails key from this same folder and terminal, and found no problem with it.  Folders name is ISO on my desktop. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Yes but not via Mac directions. Built my own Linux workstation and did it on that platform. For mac though, simply make sure its in a file folder directly and it should pick up the signature data correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the 3-rd file. There are 3. I now ordered Simson's PGP book. Good luck.

Comment: Nice. GPGTools for Mac has always served me well on that platform